# 2x3 repeated measures for skewed data

Tags: repeated-measures

I am using 2x3 repeated measures ANOVA. I am analyzing three years of test data and comparing two different groups. However, my data is negatively skewed.

What is the best way to transform negatively skewed data? What shall I use for repeated measure analysis of non normal data?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a transformation function to the data. The same transformation must be applied to all the samples. For example taking the logarithm of both sample values can lower the skew to the right.

Use the ladder of powers if log does not work.

3 cube
2 square
1 no transformation
1/2 square root
1/3 cube root
0 log
-.5 reciprocal root
-1 reciprocal
-2 reciprocal squared

If the data is right skewed try functions from the bottom.
If the data is left skewed try function from the top.

Good luck